# failed to make the source of android 6.0 ,

Tags: android, makefile

> WORKING_DIR/frameworks/base/docs/html/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.jd:-980:
>   error 101: Unresolved link/see tag
>   "android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder#View.DragShadowBuilder()" in
>   [null]
>   WORKING_DIR/frameworks/base/docs/html/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.jd:-980:
>   error 101: Unresolved link/see tag
>   "android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder#View.DragShadowBuilder(View)" in
>   [null] frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/job/JobScheduler.java:22:
>   error 101: Unresolved link/see tag
>   "android.app.job.JobInfo.Builder#JobInfo.Builder(int,android.content.ComponentName)"
>   in android.app.job.JobScheduler
>   frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java:19490: error 101:
>   Unresolved link/see tag "#View.DragShadowBuilder()" in
>   android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder
>   frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java:19490: error 101:
>   Unresolved link/see tag "#View.DragShadowBuilder(View)" in
>   android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder DroidDoc took 161 sec. to write
>   docs to out/target/common/docs/doc-comment-check 4 个警告
>   build/core/droiddoc.mk:165: recipe for target
>   'out/target/common/docs/doc-comment-check-timestamp' failed make: ***
>   [out/target/common/docs/doc-comment-check-timestamp] Error 45

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using JDK8, Android 6.0 requirement is JDK7. Tested that works well with openjdk7.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recompiling the `sdk` (`make sdk`).
I could go further with the compilation by changing several occurrences of :

```
android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder#View.DragShadowBuilder(View)
```

into,

```
android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder#DragShadowBuilder(View)
```

both in the comment of the java and in the jd files.